# Rails - Listing records of a model in a static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to call records of a model (listing all records like Posts.all) to a view that is binded to another controller.

So, I want to reach the index action of Posts_controller which contains the .all listing and .group_by listing that I want to reach and list them in a static page that is listed in Pages_controller (named as yonetim)

This is just for listing the posts for admin view (like the listing in active admin).

I think, I dont need to post any code because the question is quite abstract, but if needed I will edit the question.

*** Edit for clarifying***

**This is my posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    load_and_authorize_resource

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('postdate DESC')
        @posts_by_month = @posts.group_by { |post| post.postdate.strftime('%m - %Y')}
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:id, :title, :body, :postdate)
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

As it can be seen it is a basic blog application. Visitors that reach the root_path (posts#index routed) can see the post records based on grouping of month and year.

What I want to add is reaching the new, edit destroy and index.@posts from a static page that I create for the purpose of admin interface (similar to active Admin gem).

** This is the pages_controller.rb **

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def yonetim
    end
end
```

So when I hit /yonetim (routed to get pages#yonetim), I want the user to see the index action of posts controller with link to new, show, edit and destroy of the record.

***The system also have devise with admin boolean and cancan so if the user not signed in or don't have the authorization for admin usage, they are moved to root_path with an exception.

My problem rises that, I have tried nearly everything to list the @posts records of posts#index method in the pages/yonetim view or in the pages_controller.rb yonetim method.

So that I can list them in my admin view and work around with them.

If anything else is required just let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Mustafa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options here for `pages#yonetim`:

1. Just Redirect to 'posts#index'
2. Assign view variables (`@posts` and `@posts_by_month`) like in `posts#index` and render template `posts/index`.
3. Assign view variables (`@posts` and `@posts_by_month`) like in `posts#index` and render template `pages/index` (the default view in this case).

The drawback for the first two options is that all links (new/edit/destroy) will link to the `PostsController` and not to the `PagesController`, because you are re-using the views that were created for the `PostsController`.

Comment: Any chance for you to explain further of the 2nd and 3rd options? Cause I don't want to redirect option and didn't really understand / make it work of 3rd option.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I have completed the process based on your 3rd option.
I have added posts and posts_by_month into the yonetim method of pages controller and I could listed them in the yonetim page view. I didnt use the rendering template (not sure how and couldn't figured out).
For edit and destroy, I am calling the main controllers edit and destroy methods inside the yonetim page and not allowing them to be called without the authorization.

Thanks for the solution.